# IPython SVG renderer produces wrong text in VSCode on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, svg, jupyter, ipython, pygraphviz

I'm working with python and I created a custom class with a `draw` method which returns a `graphviz.Digraph` object. Inside a Jupyter Notebook, when trying to render this object using VSCode built-in renderer, I get wrong results, specifically in the text written over the edges.

I tried to render the object both directly (putting the object as last line of the cell) and indirectly, first producing an `.svg` file and then displaying it with `IPython.display.SVG()`:
[direct rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUdhl.png)
[indirect rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omYnP.png)

Opening the aforementioned file with other programs, like any browser, gives correct results.
Also running the notebook in JupyterLab gives correct results. I couldn't load the `.svg` file directly in this post, thus you can find it at [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AMZxeN9OGQo9dbVqgAQvw1hU6R_NWRqq/view?usp=sharing)

The fact that wrong results are produced even in the indirect method makes me suppose that the problem lies in the way VSCode renders SVG files, but I lack knowledge to solve this issue.

Comment: what do you expect it to look like? give a picture. also, are you sure it's not due to font differences or rendering engine differences? what's the rendering engine for whatever you're comparing this with?